# Is it right to define native method as public native synchronized int doSum(int a, int b)?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a confusion for JNI implementation under multithreaded environment. I have a java class as below, representing native interface:

```
public class Test {
    public native int doSum(int a, int b);
}
```

And the corresponding native method is implemented in c.

Now, My Question is, I have multiple threads, say 5. and all of them are using one global instance of above class Test. So, is it possible that the native method code, written in C,  will be thread safe? OR do do I need to make it thread safe like mentioned in the question?

And What if I create individual instance of Test class for each thread, and then call the native function? Will that behave thread safe?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't tell without knowing the implementation of the method. If the implementation is thread-safe, no need for synchronized. If it isn't thread-safe, synchronized could make it thread-safe or not. It all depends on the code of the method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it right to define native method as public native synchronized int doSum(int a, int b)?

It is right if you want it to be a synchronized method that takes two integer arguments and returns an integer result. Only you know that.

> So, is it possible that the native method code, written in C, will be thread safe?

It's possible if it is implemented that way. Impossible to say without seeing the code.

> OR do do I need to make it thread safe like mentioned in the question?

You need to make it thread-safe if its implementation isn't already thread-safe and your usage patterns require it to be thread-safe. This is not a real question.

Comment: My real requirement is to pass object address (pointer) as integer parameter to native function like int doSum(Math* objPtr, jint a, jint b). and in the body of doSum(...), I will do objPtr->Sum(a, b). What you suggest for this kind of structure? Will it be thread safe without defining synchronized?

Comment: You keep asking questions that only you know the answer to. Whether a method is thread-safe depends on what's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything specifically about Java methods implemented in C, but in both C and Java individually, there is no guarantee of thread safety without explicit synchronization. It's  possible for two threads to concurrently execute the same method.

"Thread safety" implies that a method can tolerate this under all circumstances. Imagine that thread A executes half of the method, then is paused while thread B executes some of it, then is resumed... This can lead to bugs that are very difficult to diagnose, so it's best to be careful.

In general, if the method is reading or modifying any part of the object's state, then it should either be synchronized or be kept local to a single thread.

There's a lot of good reading on this topic. I'd recommend picking up an introductory book about concurrent programming if you're interested. :)